# WCErrorCodeDeliveryFailed: Payload could not be delivered

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-3, watchconnectivity, wcsession

I'm working on an app that share data between iPhone and Apple Watch, using `WCSession` method  `sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:`

After implementing that method I get the error like:

WCSession _onqueue_notifyOfMessageError:withErrorHandler: errorHandler: YES with WCErrorCodeDeliveryFailed.

Error = Payload could not be delivered.

```
import Foundation
import WatchKit
import WatchConnectivity

class ResultInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    let applicationData = ["name": "ViratKohli"]
    self.sendToPhone(data: applicationData)
}

func sendToPhone(data: [String: Any]) {

    if WCSession.isSupported() {

        let session = WCSession.default
        session().delegate = self
        session().activate()

        if WCSession.default().isReachable {

            session().sendMessage(data, replyHandler: {(_ replyMessage: [String: Any]) -> Void in

                print("ReplyHandler called = \(replyMessage)")
                WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(WKHapticType.notification)
            }, 
            errorHandler: {(_ error: Error) -> Void in

                print("Error = \(error.localizedDescription)")
            })
         }
    }
}
....
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200630/wcsession-sendmessagereplyhandler-error-code-7014-wcerrorcodedeliveryfailed) does help you?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner nope. That didn't

Answer (score 16):

1. Do you have `session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage
   message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) ->
   Void)` on ios side's WCSessionDelegate?
2. Are you calling `replyHandler()` inside this method?

Pay attention that `session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any])` will be called only for messages sent without replyHandler.

Comment: This is the correct answer. If a `replyHandler` is provided but the other app does not implement the variant with `replyHandler`, the request will fail.

Comment: Thanks, struggled with watch > phone communication until I read this post/answer and tried the `session:message:replyHandler:` + call `replyHandler()` route!

Comment: Thank you! works great

Answer (score 11):

I was in the same trouble. If you are sending a message with a replyHandler , you'll have to use

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {

}
```

instead of

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {

}
```

for receiving messages.